# PathDelim VS DirectorySeparatorChar

Tags: delphi, io, delphi-10.1-berlin

One can use either

- System.IOUtils.TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar

OR

- System.SysUtils.PathDelim

Are there any particular differences, benefits using one over another part from System.IOUtils.TPath is more object oriented interface?

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils

Comment: It depends if you want to target multiple platforms. PathDelim seems to be limited to Windows while TPath is valid for all OS.

Comment: @whosrdaddy No, `PathDelim` supports all platforms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`System.SysUtils.PathDelim` was introduced in Delphi 6 / Kylix 1, as a means to enable the writing of platform independent code. The introduction of Kylix, the original Delphi Linux compiler, meant that for the first time Delphi code executed on a *nix platform, as well as its original target of Windows.

`System.IOUtils.TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar` is part of the `IOUtils` unit that was introduced more recently to support the current wave of cross-platform tooling, which supports MacOS, iOS, Android and will soon encompass Linux once more.

Where you have a choice between `System.SysUtils` and `System.IOUtils`, you are generally expected to use the latter. The `System.IOUtils` is the cross-platform unit for file system support. That said, you commonly would not use `DirectorySeparatorChar` directly, but instead would use methods like `System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine`.

Answer (score 3):

`TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar` is defined in `System.IOUtils` as

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  FDirectorySeparatorChar := '\';    // DO NOT LOCALIZE;
  // ...
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
  FDirectorySeparatorChar := '/';    // DO NOT LOCALIZE;
  // ...
{$ENDIF}
```

while `PathDelim` is defined in `System.SysUtils` as

```
PathDelim  = {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} '\'; {$ELSE} '/'; {$ENDIF}
```

While the conditionals are slightly different, they would only differ if neither or both of `MSWINDOWS` and `POSIX` were defined, which is not the case for any platform. And if there would be such a platform in the future, the declarations would surely be fixed accordingly.

TL;DR: There is no difference, you can use either based on your preference.